# PGP: Decrypt empty file

Tags: c#, cmd, pgp, gnupg

I am trying to decrypt file with following code:

```
Process process = Process.Start(psi);
string command = @"echo " + password + "|gpg.exe --passphrase-fd 0 --batch --verbose --yes --output " + decryptedFilePath + @" --decrypt """ + encryptedFilePath;
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);
process.StandardInput.Flush();
process.StandardInput.Close();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Everything is fine until the file is not empty.
If file doesn't contain any data, PGP do not create file for me.
Do you know any option to fix it?

I know, I can check the length like that:

```
if (new FileInfo(encryptedFilePath).Length == 0)
```

and copy file with different extension, but i wish more elegant solution, like e.g. some option for command to force creating the file even if it's empty, or sth like that :)

Comment: If the file is zero length or does not exist and you desire an empty output file don't pass it to PGP just `File.CreateText(decryptedFilePath).Close();`

Comment: Ok, but it is still solution for creating new file via .net library.
Does it mean there is no option to force creating file via PGP?